# How to avoid downloading the POST body in a WCF server?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, stream

I have a WCF server running with a WebHttpBinding. Sometimes my code in the server discards POST requests based on Header values only.

How do I avoid WCF from downloading the body?

(I am monitoring the network card performance counters and it takes no impact the fact that I don't open or used the "Stream body" and just return from the handling method)

PS: I have this set in my binding: TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this blog on WCF streaming inside
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/03/25/wcf-streaming-inside-data-contracts.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paolos/archive/2010/05/25/large-message-transfer-with-wcf-adapters-part-1.aspx

hope it helps